# Port Mapping not working for container created using tomcat image

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am running Docker Desktop on my Windows 10 machine.
The container gets created and started successfully on executing the command `docker run -d -p 1234:8080 tomcat`.
While the container is running, when I am hitting the URL http://localhost:1234
404-Not Found is coming.
Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

404 Not Found means you reached the server but the page is not found. place an index.html file at the root of your tomcat webserver and you'll get that page in that address